# Get and pass array values from Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Bit of background info - the developer of the system we use has left the company and I've been asked to add a few new features. Needless to say, there's no documentation and to make matters worse I'm an absolute novice so am having to learn as I go along. I'm kind of managing to do most things but have come totally stuck on this problem. For anyone kind enough to help me out, if you could really dumb any answers down that would be great. So, the problem........

HTML page that is dynamically populated with a list of items. For each item in the list there's a checkbox, and for each checkbox that's ticked I need to update a MySQL database. The code that adds the checkboxes to the page is

```
echo("<td class=\"tableRight\" style=\"width: 5%\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"costume[]\" value=\"".$costume['id']."\" id=\"costume_".$costume['id']."\" onclick=\"tickrow(".$costume['id'].");\" /></td>");
```

The JavaScript file is loaded in the page head with

```
<script src=\"costume-list.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>
```

The button's code that should kick off the database update is

```
echo("<div class=\"navContainer\" onClick=\"batch_move() \" class=\"navItem\">");
echo("<img src=\"/resource/img/icon/move.png\" border=\"0\" /><br />Batch Move Costumes");
echo("</a></div>");
```

And finally the JavaScript I've managed to put together is

```
function batch_move() {

var combo = document.getElementById("cbo_title");
var move_to = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text;
var move_to_id = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].value;

if (move_to.length==0) {
alert("Please select the location you want to move the costumes to.");
return;
}

var resp_move = confirm("Are you sure you want to MOVE the selected costumes to "+move_to+" ?");

if (resp_move==true) { 
   alert("Lets move em");
   window.open ("http://path-to-server/costume/batch-move-costume.php?  loc="+move_to_id+"&items="+INeedTheArrayHere,"mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=250");
}
```

}

So what I want to do is first make sure that at least one checkbox is ticked and if it is then get the values of the ticked boxes into an array to pass to the called PHP form. I can manage the update code in the opened form, it's just getting the array to it.

Sorry for long post, but hope that's enough info. If there's anything else you need to know please ask and I'll supply more details. Many thanks

Comment: can you please add your html also

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have my deepest sympathy. It totally sucks to get something like this mess dumped on you. This should help:

```
var valString = "";
var list = document.querySelectorAll('input[type ="checkbox"]');
for(var node in list) {
    if(list[node].checked) {
        valString += list[node].name + ','; 
        //you will need to add a name property when you create the html
        //<input type='checkbox' name='dress'>Dress
    }
}
```

This will create a comma-delimited string of all the checked checkbox values that you can send to the server. You can split it into an array on the server side. You will not be able to just drop an array into the `GET` part of the url like you have 'IneedArrayHere' above, hence the string. Also, if there are too many selections (URLS have a length limit) you will need to switch from `GET` to `POST`, which is a whole other issue.

P.S. I highly recommend that you take all those escaped double quotes and make them unescaped single quotes. That sort of thing is done by people who are used to things like `SQL` varieties where the difference between single and double quotes is significant, but in `javascript` and most (all?) sever-side languages (like `php`) the difference is irrelevant.

Comment: `value` will return an empty string unless you specify a 'value' property on the tag (or js representation thereof). This is a consequence of `HTML` overloading the input tag to represent textboxes (which have a value) and checkboxes/radio buttons (which technically don't). The text in front of the checkbox is just text (not a property of the input element itself), and there isn't necessarily a great way to get at it, its easier to put a property on the tag and retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
    var collection =document.getElementById("boxes").getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
    var res =[];
    for (var x=0; x < collection.length; x++) {
        if (collection[x].type.toUpperCase()=='CHECKBOX')
            var b = [collection[x].name ,collection[x].checked ] ;
            res[res.length] = b;
    }
    alert(JSON.stringify(res));
}
</script>
<html>
<div id="boxes">
<input type="checkbox" name="1" value="1">eded</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="2" value="2">eded</input>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="ok">
<html>
```

Now you can simply send the JSON to  the server.

Answer (score 0):

many thanks for your answer. I've plugged in your code into the JavaScript and ticked a few of the checkboxes on the form. When the code runs I get the first prompt message, but not the message box with a the value of valString ?.

It's obviously something I'm doing wrong - as I said I'm a complete novice and struggling to get to grips with this system I seem to have inherited (not through choice!)

Current code looks like this, and any pointers to my latest mistake would be much appreciated

```
function batch_move() {

var combo = document.getElementById("cbo_title");
var move_to = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text;
var move_to_id = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].value;

if (move_to.length==0) {
alert("Please select the location you want to move the costumes to.");
return;
}

var resp_move = confirm("Are you sure you want to MOVE the selected costumes to "+move_to+" ?");

var valString = "";
var list = document.querySelectorAll('input[type ="checkbox"]');
for(var node in list) {
if(list[node].checked) {
valString += list[node].name + ','; 
}
}

alert(valString);

if (resp_move==true) { 
alert("Lets move em");
window.open ("http://path-to-server/costume/batch-move-costume.php?loc="+move_to_id+"&items=2,3,4,5","mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=250");
}

}
```

Comment: do you know  jQuery ? it will be much easier with jQuery